# How to create 24hour SeekBar or ProgressBar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I have a SeekBar that I want to represent a 24 hour period. I would like for each step to mean 5 minutes. Is this possible? The default SeekBar has a max value of 100 units; by which I guess each step is 1 unit. I remember hearing of a 10,000 unit possibility. In any case, is what I seek to accomplish possible? 24 hours by 5-minute interval/step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update the `onProgressChanged` method.

```
int interval = 5;
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) 
{
    progress = (progress/interval) * interval;
    seekBar.setProgress(progress);   
}
```

Also set the `max` value for the `Seekbars` `xml`. *1440* represents the number of minutes in 24 hours

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/SeekBar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:max="1440"/>
```

Comment: The bar is to be scrolled by user. Whenever I set the max value, my seek bar can no longer scroll.

Comment: It should be able to. Perhaps it's a layout issue. You could also try setting the max pragmatically `sb1.setMax(1440);` or by giving your seekbar a `progress` attribute of 5. This should do the same thing.

Comment: Ah ok! No worries. Good to hear